# Using the Same Class with One Method Being Overridden

Tags: c#, overriding

I am using an instance of a `class A`. However, I want to replace one of the methods in that class with something else. I understand I can write a different class and inherit the original class but I am not supposed to touch the part of the code that declares the instance.

I have tried creating `class B` with that particular method overridden but clearly this won't work since the thread in `class A` has been started in `Main()` already. Here's an example of the code. Appreciate the help!!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        /* The Original Class A that I am Not Supposed to Touch */
        public class A
        {
            public A()
            {
                Thread thread_A = new Thread(Method1);
                thread_A.Start();
            }
            public void Method1()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Method2();
                }

            }

            /* I Want To Replace This Method with Something Else */
            public virtual void Method2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is in Class A");
            }

        }
        /* Some Random Class I Created Myself that I Do Not Know If It Works */
        public class B: A
        {
            /* The Method that I Want To Use */
            public override void Method2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is in Class B");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* I am not supposed to touch this either, it has to be an instance of A */
            A instanceA = new A();

            /* But I want the print result to be "This is in Class B" */
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Scenario: `Class A` is used to continuously send messages through a websocket. There is a method in `Class A` that wraps the message. Now I am trying to wrap the message with a different format. So the method I am trying to replace is in the middle of the execution in `Class A`. The thread of `Class A` sending the messages has been started already in some other file I can't touch...

Update: If I have to make changes in `A`, is there any suggestions on how I can nicely override the method just for this project? Since `A` is a common file shared by different projects.

Comment: Sorry, the limitations that have been set pretty much handcuff you getting the job done.

Comment: Do you need to access state in `class A`?  Or do you just need code to execute?  You could have `class  B` take `class A` in it's constructor and have `class A` as a property, then execute whatever method you need with your newly created Method.

Comment: To replace virtual method you have to use inheritance. But I don't know what you suppose to do with restriction `A instanceA = new A()`... now I also want to know the answer to that puzzle.

Comment: The requirements you have make no sense. 1) if they are actual requirements for an actual real life scenario, they make no sense, as you can't hack in a new method into A. 2) if they are part of requirements meant to test your knowledge on C#, they make no sense, as if you can find a way to hack that method to produce the text instead (without touching A), then nobody would do that in real life code. This is, in that case, testing your knowledge about esoteric stuff in C#.

Comment: Overriding is the right aproach here, but you  would also need to have your Main() use your class B instead of A.

Comment: Can you tell us about a concrete scenario where your constraints apply?  There are kinda-sorta solutions to problems somewhat similar to yours, but they only make sense in certain conditions (consider producing boilerplate code that users can play with using partial classes and partial methods).  I'm not saying any of these make sense here - but knowing why you are asking might help

Comment: @Sinatr `Class A` is used to continuously send messages through a websocket. There is a method in `Class A` that wraps the message. Now I am trying to wrap the message with a different format. So the method I am trying to replace is in the middle of the execution in `Class A`...

Comment: Your question perfectly illustrates the problem of being coupled. If you can't change `new A()` to something else, then the only other way to make a change is to change `A`. But if you do that, you'll affect every other place where `A` is used. The result - you can't change one part without changing something else. Unfortunately the solution starts with not having a class depend directly on `A` - in other words, *not* calling `new A()`. We can give answers that explain why the problem can't be solved without changing the requirements, but not solutions that work within your requirements.

Comment: Override it in B.

Comment: However, if you want to be able to change the format on the fly, injecting a format strategy might be better. But all of these require you to make changes to A.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I can talk to my supervisor about making changes to `A`. But there is no way I can avoid using the instance of `A`. I understand it would be much cleaner if I just override it in B and use B but the thread in A has been started already

Comment: There isn't a way to solve this problem without writing another version of Method3 and Method2

Comment: The best way I could think of right now is to add an `if` statement in `Method1` to check which project is this, and then choose which version of `Method2` to use. So that all I need is to add my version of `Method2` in `Method1` without needing to rewrite the whole class or `Method3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've describing is effectively unsolvable within the constraints you've given. That's not an answer that tells you how to do what you're trying to do, but if the answer is that it's impossible, well, that's the answer. But we can still look at why it's impossible and what we can do instead.

Your code does this:

```
A instanceA = new A();
```

You can't change the behavior of this code without either changing what `A` does or changing this code to *not* use `A`. One of those constraints must change.

This illustrates coupling, which is when different parts of our code are tied to each other so that they can't work separately and we can't change one part without changing something else.

Here's an example that doesn't use names like `A` and `B` because that becomes confusing to read. I didn't overthink this too much - it's just an example to illustrate a point:

```
public class Stove
{
    public void CookFood() { }
}

public class Chef
{
    public void MakeFood()
    {
        var stove = new Stove();
        stove.CookFood();
    } 
}

public class Parent
{
    public void FeedChildren()
    {
        var stove = new Stove();
        stove.CookFood();
    }
}
```

Neither one of these classes can work without `Stove`. In a sense you could say that `Stove` is part of them. If you change `Stove`, you are in effect changing both of these classes. You also can't test either one of these classes without testing `Stove`.

What's more, because both of these classes are coupled to `Stove`, they are also coupled *to each other.* If one of these classes needs `Stove` to do something different, you'll have to change `Stove`. The result will affect the other class. That means changes to `Chef` can affect `Parent` and vice versa.

That's undesirable. It makes our application work like one big class instead of having smaller pieces that can change independently.

A common way to eliminate such coupling is to depend on abstractions instead of concrete implementations. We could change our code to look like this:

```
public interface IStove
{
    void CookFood();
}

public class Chef
{
    private readonly IStove _stove;

    public Chef(IStove stove)
    {
        _stove = stove;
    }

    public void FeedChildren()
    {
        _stove.CookFood();
    } 
}

public class Parent
{
    private readonly IStove _stove;

    public Parent(IStove stove)
    {
        _stove = stove;
    }

    public void MakeFood()
    {
        _stove.CookFood();
    }
}
```

Now neither class depends on the concrete class, `Stove`. Both depend on an abstraction - in this case an interface - `IStove`.

If I've got a `Stove` class and it meets the needs of both `Chef` and `Parent`, both can use it. But what if I need a different `Stove`, like a `Grill` or `GiantPizzaOven`? Now I can create a different class that implements `IStove`. I don't have to change existing classes.

Now no class is coupled to an implementation of `IStove`, and they're not coupled to each other. We can change `Chef`, `Parent`, or `Stove` independently without forcing changes to other classes.

---

The pattern of passing dependencies like `IStove` via the constructor instead of having classes create them (`new Stove()`) is dependency injection. It's a useful pattern and I highly recommend reading about it and trying it. Eventually you might come to depend on it (no pun intended) but it's beyond the scope of this answer.

---

One more detail - you may have noticed that there is no class inheritance in this answer. It's not that inheritance is bad, but it can be. It's another way to introduce coupling. It might make sense for one implementation of `IStove` to inherit from another, but it's just as likely that it will introduce other problems.

My suggestion then is to beware of solutions to this sort of problem that *start* with inheritance. Look for solutions that don't involve inheritance, only use it when it begins to make obvious sense, and if you create inheritance, don't hesitate to undo it and look for other solutions as soon as it gets messy.

---

Yet another detail: Depending on an interface like `IStove` reduces the problem, but as our code gets more complex, even for different classes to depend on the same abstraction can somewhat couple them together. That problem is addressed with the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2019/01/01/interface-segregation-principle-applied.html). It's just something to have on the radar.

Comment: Very interesting example! The `Class A` in my example is actually an inheritance of another class. Although they did not expect the wrapping could be different now. I actually just talked to the author of the code and he suggested me to make another class just to make it easier to read, which I think it is for good practice as well. Thank you very much for the help! Again, great example!